# Working with load more request with scrapy python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a site using scrapy, My spider is as follows:

```
class AngelSpider(Spider):


    name = "angel"
    allowed_domains = ["angel.co"]

    start_urls = (

        "https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=India",


    )
    def start_requests(self):
        page_size = 25
        headers ={

        'Host': 'angel.co',
        'Origin': 'https://angel.co',
        'User-Agent': 'Scrapy spider',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept':   '*/*',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Referer': 'https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=India',

        'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
        }



        for offset in (0, 200, page_size):
            yield Request('https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data',
                          method='POST',
                          headers=headers,
                          body=urllib.urlencode(
                              {'action': 'more',
                               'filter_data[locations][]':'India',
                                 'sort':'signal',
                                 'page':2}))




    def parse(self, response):
        nestd =[]
        company = {}
        val = response.xpath('//div[@data-_tn = "companies/trending/row" ]')
        company_name = response.xpath("//div[@data-_tn = 'companies/trending/row' ]//div//div//div//div[@class='name']//text()").extract()
        #company_link = val.xpath("//div//div//div[@class ='photo']//@href").extract()
        #company_tag_line =val.xpath("//div//div//div//div//div[@class='pitch u-colorGray6']//text()").extract()
        #company_from = val.xpath("//div//div//div//div//a[@name]//text()").extract()
        print company_name
```

But it's not yielding any data.  Is there another way I can simulate the load more articles button to load the articles and continue the scraper?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, the website first does a POST request to https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data, which returns JSON data containing the startup ids, like this:

```
{
    "ids": [
        146538,277273,562440,67592,124939,...,460951
    ],
    "total": 18443,
    "page": 2,
    "sort": "signal",
    "new": false,
    "hexdigest": "a8ef7331cba6a01e5d2fc8f5cc3e04b69871f62f"
}
```

After that, the website does a GET request to https://angel.co/companies/startups, passing the values from the JSON above as URL parameters.

So, the requests generated in your `start_requests` should be handled by another callback, that should read the JSON data returned as response and build the URL to get the actual startups list in HTML format.

Comment: And how those params exactly should look like based on "ids"? Could you give an example?

Comment: r = requests.get("https://angel.co/companies/startups/:id", headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}, params=urllib.urlencode({"startup_id":3725508})) does not work

Answer (score -1):

The website you're trying to scrap uses javascript, you either have to use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to emulate the browser.

Comment: You actually don't need to use a JS engine in cases like this, where all the info you need is returned after a few XmlHttpRequests. Check out this post: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016/

Comment: I had used selenium but still won't able to scrape the data link to my spider is https://codeshare.io/vLqat take a look on it